# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined json data

Tags: javascript, typeahead.js

I am working on typeahead.js script here am not getting correct response,i have tried many things but not working.
this url is returning jason data from php file...

```
var result = (function( )
{
    var val = document.getElementById('sel_fac').value;
    var city = document.getElementById('select_city').value;
    var query = document.getElementById('typeaheadfield').value;
    var url = 'search.php?fac=' + val + '&city=' + city + '&key=' + query;
    console.log(url);
    makeRequest(url, function(data) {
        var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    });
    function makeRequest(url, callback) {
        var request;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            request = new XMLHttpRequest(); // IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        } else {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); // IE6, IE5
        }
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
                callback(request);
            }
        }
        request.open("GET", url, true);
        request.send();
    }
})();
// console.log(result);

var substringMatcher = function(strs) {
 console.log(strs);
    return function findMatches(q, cb) {
        var matches, substringRegex;
        //  console.log(strs);
        window.alert(strs);
        // an array that will be populated with substring matches
        matches = [];

        // regex used to determine if a string contains the substring `q`
        substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');

        // iterate through the pool of strings and for any string that
        // contains the substring `q`, add it to the `matches` array
        $.each(strs, function(i, str) {
            if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
                matches.push(str);
                window.alert(str);
                // console.log(str);    
            }
        });

        cb(matches);
    };
};
```

when i am trying with this jason data getting correct result.

//    var result1 = ["Gold's Gym Hiranandani", "Golds Gym Marol Naka", "Gold's Gym Chembur", "Gold's Gym Bandra West", "Gold's Gym Kandivali East", "Gold's Gym Lower Parel", "Gold's Gym Vashi", "Gold's Gym Kandiwali west", "Gold's Gym Mulund West", "Gold's Gym - Mona Fitness Centre Private Limited", "Gold's Gym Borivali west", "Jignya Johri @ Gold's Gym", "Gold's Gym Thane West", "Golds Gym Khar west", "Gold's Gym Grant Road (W)"];

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#typeaheadfield').typeahead({
        hint: true,
        highlight: true,
        minLength: 1,
        limit: 10
    },
    {
        name: 'fac_name',
        source: substringMatcher(result)
    });
    window.alert(result);
    console.log(result ? result.length : 'result is null or undefined');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function setting the result is asynchronous. It cannot return the data instantly, so while it waits for it, it keeps executing the code below it. To prevent that, use a callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var result = []; // <--------------------------Define the variable (empty array)

  (function() {
    /* ... */
    makeRequest(url, function(data) {
      var data = JSON.parse(data.responseText);
      //return data;  <--------------------------Remove this
      result = data; // <------------------------Set the value of result
      keepGoing(); // <--------------------------Execute a callback
    });
    /* ... */
  })();

  console.log(result); // <----------------------Empty array, data not received yet

  function keepGoing() {
    console.log(result); // <--------------------Should be available now
  }

});
```